# Is "little of fun" correct?

Tags: negation, quantifiers

I watched a class in which the teacher was explaining how to use quantifiers. One of her examples was "I had **lots of** fun last night". However, she used the example "I didn't have **little of** fun last night" in a substitution exercise, which is part of a regular class.

Is the expression **little of fun** correct? I mean, according to the English grammar?
Do people really say that? Google returned over 300 thousand results for **little of fun**, while there were over 8 million for **little fun**.

I would have said "I didn't have little fun last night" instead.

Comment: In my estimation, "little of fun" is not idiomatic English.

Comment: Neither I nor anyone I know (native-speaker-wise) would say "I had a little of fun". That said, neither would we say "I *didn't* have little fun last night". We'd usually say "I didn't have *any* fun last night" or simply "I didn't have fun last night".

Comment: *Little fun* is the usual idiomatic form, as you discovered. But *little of fun* is grammatical and might possibly be used idiomatically in certain contexts e.g. *The general population of the Daesh-occupied regions of Syria have few of the considered essentials of life, and experience little of fun or recreation in their lives*.

Comment: @WS2 Your example has a negative meaning and it is short for little of fun or little of recreation.

Comment: @DanBron, what you say if you had actually had fun, but not much, just little? "I had little fun last night" or "I had little of fun last night"?

Comment: @LoureiroGui It's the little words that are the trickiest. To say I had a small amount of fun last night, not too much, I'd say "I had **a** little fun last night"; if I were to omit the *a* (the indefinite article) and say "I had little fun last night", it would mean (essentially sarcastically), I had *no fun at all*: I did not enjoy myself; I did not have a good time. No one would say "I had a little *of* fun", with or without the *a*; the preposition *of* is simply unidiomatic there. But notice you *can't* negate the "correct" way by just adding "didn't". That doesn't work.

Comment: I had some fun last night.

Comment: @DanBron, what you've just said is partially new to me. I've known the expression "a little" for quite a long time. However, it was taught to me that it has a negative/not suffient idea, while "little" has the idea of small but satisfactory/ok ammount. So "I had a little fun" would be "I'd like to have had more fun", whereas "I had little fun" would be "I didn't have much fun, but it was ok". What can you say about these ideas?

Comment: @StevenLittman, you've found the easiest path with "some", which is the one I usually teach to my students. However, I'd like to learn the hard one, too ^^

Comment: You _found_ over 300 thousand results for "little of fun" on Google? Or you did a Google search, and saw that number reported on the first page? (I saw that number reported, too, but Google couldn't show me more than a few hundred when I tried to page through the results.)

Comment: I think this question should be closed as the OP might have misunderstood what the teacher said. The question itself doesn't make sense. No English teacher would use that example as the opposite to the first one.

Comment: @J.R. I have had similar experiences too with Google NGrams - which together with other things makes me very sceptical about them

Comment: @WS2 That's because it shows "a little of fun" mostly. The OP is misleading us and it has nothing to do with Google results. .

Comment: @LoureiroGui Nothing new to add to my previous comment, really. I had *a little* fun meant I had some fun. I had *little* fun means I did not have fun. That's all.

Comment: @LoureiroGui:  why are you looking for a hard path? Perhaps the easy path is the only sensible one.  When you haven't had a lot of fun, you've just had some fun.  If you want to use "little," it's more colloquial to include "very":  I had very little fun.  In the negative, I didn't have much fun.

Comment: "A little bit of fun" is idiomatic for a small amount of enjoyment.  Or, "I had very little fun last night," if you wish to convey that very little fun was had.

Comment: @LoureiroGui: I think you have _little_ and _a little_ back to front. _Little_ is the one that takes negative polarity words such as _any_. Consider "Little of the text makes any sense", but "A little of the text makes some sense". You could omit "any" and "some" from those sentences, but you could not swap them over.

Comment: @DanBron Is the following an exception? why? _I'll have a little of everything_  https://www.thefreedictionary.com/little

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of "lots of" is "little", not "little of". In that you are correct.

However, the teacher made another mistake, by using a double negative. There are two ways to make an opposite to "I had lots of fun", you can either negate the "had" or the "lots of":

> I had little fun
>
> I didn't have lots of fun

Answer (score 0):

While saying "I didn't have little fun last night" would not be correct, saying "I had no little amount of fun last night" would. Why?

There is a weird figure of speech in English called litotes (lie' toe tease) which uses a double negative in creative ways. For example, in keeping with your "lots of fun" quantifier, with litotes you could say,

> We had no little amount of fun last night.

Translation: We had lots of fun last night. By negating *lots*, you get *little*. Then by negating *little*, you imply *lots*!

Just to reinforce this strange figure of litotes, consider the following two sentences. Which one contains litotes?

> 1. There was a huge crowd at the party last night.
> 2. There was no small crowd at last night's party.

Sentence #2 used litotes.

Is there any particular reason a person would choose to use litotes instead of the more normal way of expressing a thought? I suggest two reasons. First, litotes introduces a variety in the way a thought would normally be expressed. Variety is good. For this reason, however, its use should not be overdone, or then the ab-norm becomes the norm.

Second, by negating the opposite of what would normally be said, folks with an ironic bent may use litotes to satisfy a certain desire within them to express things ironically, for irony, too, delights in the conflict of negatives, as when the literal is negated by the figurative.

Speaking ironically about last night's party, you could say to a person who simply *loves* interpersonal conflict,

> I heard there were lots of fights, plenty of heated arguments, and no small number of insults and barbs traded back and forth at the party last night. You must have had a blast!

Comment: No, it would be "no small amount of fun".

Comment: @HotLicks: Po tah to, po ta to; to mah to, to ma to; puh jah muz, puh jam uz . . ..